# python subclassing: TypeError object.__new__() takes no parameters

Tags: python, subclassing

Ok I'm stumped again! This should be easy though ;-)

I'm trying to subclass the pytables class `tables.IsDefinition`, as follows:

```
import tables

class doc(tables.IsDescription):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
```

And then I try to instantiate it I get an error:

```
doc('test')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

...<ipython console> in <module>()

TypeError: object.__new__() takes no parameters
```

This is with Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41) and IPython 0.10

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know PyTables, but from quick Google search it seems `IsDescription` is a metaclass, not a class.

Comment: Ah ok ... the manual doesn't make that clear. Thanks for the pointer

Comment: @CatPlusPlus It looks like you should post your comment as an answer so that it can be accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else lands here, the answer is that `IsDescription` is a "metaclass". More information can be found on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python)